# Checking login always sends them to the home page (action went user is not logged in)

Tags: php

I am trying to verify if they are logged in and my code is not working. Here is my login.php

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "";
    $passcode = "";
    $dbname = "";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $passcode, $dbname);

    if (!$conn)
    {
        echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">
                Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                });
                var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement Error", {
                    icon: "app/logo.png",
                    body: "Failed to establish a connection to the database"
                });
            </script>
        ';
        die();
    }
    else 
    {
        if (isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['pass']))
        {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
            if (empty($username))
            {
                echo '              
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        });
                        var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement Error", {
                            icon: "app/logo.png",
                            body: "Please provide a username"
                        });
                    </script>
                ';
            }
            if (empty($pass))
            {
                echo '      
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        });
                        var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement Error", {
                            icon: "app/logo.png",
                            body: "Please provide a password"
                        });
                    </script>
                ';
            }
            $query = "SELECT `ID` FROM `loginsystem` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `passcode` = '$pass'";
            if ($querySucceded = mysqli_query($conn, $query))
            {
                $queryValidate = mysqli_num_rows($querySucceded);
                if ($queryValidate == 0)
                {
                    echo '
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                                console.log(result);
                            });
                            var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement Error", {
                                icon: "app/logo.png",
                                body: "Incorrect login credentials"
                            });
                        </script>
                    ';
                }
                else if ($queryValidate == 1)
                {
                    $userId = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querySucceded);
                    $_SESSION['ID'] = $userId;
                    echo '
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        window.location.href="app/php/checkLogin.php";
                        Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        }); 
                        var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement", {
                            icon: "app/logo.png",
                            body: "Login success"
                        });
                    </script>';
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                echo '
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        });
                        var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement Error", {
                            icon: "app/logo.png",
                            body: "Query could not be performed"
                        });
                    </script>
                ';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is my checkLogin.php

```
<?php
    require("../../php/login.php");
    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                console.log('Logged user: $user');
            </script>
        ";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "http://smartlead.online/"</script>';
    }
?>
```

But regardless of the login status it always leads me to the homepage. I dont want that I want the users to be able to stay on the page if they are logged in and to go login if they are not

Fix based on comments

```
<?php
    require("../../php/login.php");
    if (isset($_SESSION['ID']) && !empty($_SESSION['ID']))
    {
        $_SESSION['ID'] = $user;
        echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                console.log('Logged user: $user');
            </script>
        ";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "http://smartlead.online/"</script>';
    }
?>
```

No good. Still does not work.

**Second edit**

```
<?php
    require("../../php/login.php");
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['ID']) && !empty($_SESSION['ID']))
    {
        $_SESSION['ID'] = $user;
        echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                console.log('Logged user: $user');
            </script>
        ";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "http://smartlead.online/"</script>';
    }
?>
```

Used session_start(); but it still doesnt work

**Edit 3**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "smartlea_reborn";
    $passcode = "1201920203Ir";
    $dbname = "smartlea_general_database";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $passcode, $dbname);

    if (!$conn)
    {
        echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">
                Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                });
                var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement Error", {
                    icon: "app/logo.png",
                    body: "Failed to establish a connection to the database"
                });
            </script>
        ';
        die();
    }
    else 
    {
        if (isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['pass']))
        {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $pass = $_POST['pass'];
            if (empty($username))
            {
                echo '              
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        });
                        var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement Error", {
                            icon: "app/logo.png",
                            body: "Please provide a username"
                        });
                    </script>
                ';
            }
            if (empty($pass))
            {
                echo '      
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        });
                        var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement Error", {
                            icon: "app/logo.png",
                            body: "Please provide a password"
                        });
                    </script>
                ';
            }
            $query = "SELECT `ID` FROM `loginsystem` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `passcode` = '$pass'";
            if ($querySucceded = mysqli_query($conn, $query))
            {
                $queryValidate = mysqli_num_rows($querySucceded);
                if ($queryValidate == 0)
                {
                    echo '
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                                console.log(result);
                            });
                            var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement Error", {
                                icon: "app/logo.png",
                                body: "Incorrect login credentials"
                            });
                        </script>
                    ';
                }
                else if ($queryValidate == 1)
                {
                    session_start();
                    $userId = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querySucceded);
                    $_SESSION['ID'] = $userId;
                    echo '
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        window.location.href = "http://smartlead.online/app/index.php";
                        Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        }); 
                        var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement", {
                            icon: "app/logo.png",
                            body: "Login success"
                        });
                    </script>';
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                echo '
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        Notification.requestPermission().then(function(result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        });
                        var notification = new Notification("Smart Lead Advertisement Error", {
                            icon: "app/logo.png",
                            body: "Query could not be performed"
                        });
                    </script>
                ';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

checkLogin.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require("../../php/login.php");
    echo $_SESSION['ID'];
    if (isset($_SESSION['ID']) && !empty($_SESSION['ID']))
    {
        $_SESSION['ID'] = $user;
        echo "
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                console.log('Logged user: $user');
            </script>
        ";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo 'Error';
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should redirect using [`header("Location: yoursite.com")`](http://php.net/header). And remember, after using `header`, `exit()` in case the user has disabled redirects.

Comment: I am actually using ajax. header doesnt work in ajax calls.

Comment: I had to find a work around it.

Comment: Anything else that may be wrong with it?

Comment: Well, you're setting `$_SESSION['ID'] = $userId;` but then you check `isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))` instead of `'ID'`. I don't see where you set the `'username'` key until after you check for it.

Comment: Ah..... I see... let me fix that.. That may just be the problem.

Comment: And you call `session_start();` somewhere before you start trying to use session variables?

Comment: Nope.. okay.. let me go try again.

Comment: I put that in login.php but it did not work.

Comment: Do I put it in checkLogin.php? Or login.php in normal cases?

Comment: You need to call it once at the start of every script. So if you're including checkLogin.php everywhere, might as well put it the top of that file

Comment: I did it no luck. It still does not work. It redirects me to the home page which is the action is the user is NOT logged in

Comment: You have to call it even before you include that login.php. session_start should always be the first thing you do before you do anything else

Answer (score 0):

In this setup PHP is not able to use session variables, because the session is never started. You should add `session_start();` on top of the checkLogin.php file.